# Writing a while loop for two sets of data for R

Tags: r, dataframe, while-loop

This is probably simple, but Im new to R and it doesn't work like GrADs so I;ve been searching high and low for examples but to no avail..

I have two sets of data. Data A (1997) and Data B (2000)
Data A has 35 headings (apples, orange, grape etc). 200 observations.
Data B has 35 headings (apples, orange, grape, etc). 200 observations.

The only difference between the two datasets is the year.

So i would like to correlate the two dataset i.e. 200 data under Apples (1997) vs 200 data under Apples (2000). So 1 heading should give me only 1 value.

I've converted all the header names to V1,V2,V3...

So now I need to do this:

```
x<-1

while(x<35) { 

   new(x)=cor(1997$V(x),2000$V(x))

   print(new(x))

}
```

and then i get this error:

> Error in pptn26$V(x) : attempt to apply non-function.

Any advise is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your code makes no sense; you have a `while` loop conditional on `x`, but `x` never changes. Is `new` a function? Where is it defined? `1997$V(x)` is not valid R code. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes directly from using parentheses where R isn't expecting them. You'll get the same type of error if you do `1(x)`. `1` is not a function, so if you put it right next to parentheses with no white space between, you're attempting to apply a non function.

I'm also a bit surprised at how you are managing to get all the way to that error, before running into several others, but I suppose that has something to do with when R evaluates what...

Here's how to get the behavior you're looking for:

```
mapply(cor, A, B)
# provided A is the name of your 1997 data frame and B the 2000
```

Here's an example with simulated data:

```
set.seed(123)
A <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = sample(10), z = rnorm(10))
B <- data.frame(x = 4:13, y = sample(10), z = rnorm(10))
mapply(cor, A, B)
#         x          y          z 
# 1.0000000  0.1393939 -0.2402058
```

In its typical usage, `mapply` takes an n-ary function and n objects that provide the n arguments for that function. Here the n-ary function is `cor`, and the objects are `A`, and `B`, each a data frame. A data frame is structured as a list of vectors, the columns of the data frame. So `mapply` will loop along your columns for you, making 35 calls to `cor`, each time with the next column of both `A` and `B`.

If you have managed to figure out how to name your data frames `1997` and `2000`, kudos. It's not easy to do that. It's also going to cause you headaches. You'll want to have a syntactically valid name for your data frame(s). That means they should start with a letter (or a dot, but really a letter). See [the R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f) for the details.

Comment: thank you so much! Yes i've figured how to change the name. 
this is much simpler than writing while loop

Comment: @MT32 you're welcome :) If this answered your question, please select it as the answer (with the checkmark). Once you have the reputation to upvote, you can also upvote answers to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @MT32 I hope you understood my point that you should NOT name your data frames (or any object) 1997. It's possible, but you shouldn't do it.